# Upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 now I can't boot Windows 7 or 10

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, usb, 16.04, windows-10

I created a boot able flash drive using this procedure:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

I then used this to upgrade Ubuntu to the current version.

After the upgrade, I can not get the windows boot loader to come up no matter what hard drive I try to boot from and the Ubuntu boot loader only shows Ubuntu where as the previous version would also give Windows as an option. What do I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

1. restart
2. press the boot menu key(for me it was f10)
3. select windows hdd
4. until now I am using these steps
5. backup your data after going to the windows os
6. search for more answers after backing it up/else do steps 1 to 4 whenever you want windows
7. Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

Boot from a Ubuntu flashdrive again and select try ubuntu option. Then install [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) on the live session and run it with recommended options. I believe it will fix the problem otherwise post the pastebin link that boot-repair provides here.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening a terminal and running `sudo update-grub`. This command should automatically search for and add all OSes found to the GRUB boot menu.

I'd recommend trying this before trying `boot-repair`.

Comment: That worked. Windows 10 loader now shows up in the GRUB boot menu and I can now boot windows again. Thanks so much! I really appreciate it!

Comment: @user536393 Just checking, can you boot Windows 7 too? I've had some problems with this before.

Comment: Yes, but Windows 7 doesn't show up in GRUB. Only windows 10 shows up in GRUB but then when I click on that it loads the windows boot loader and from their I have the choice of Windows 7 or Windows 10.

Comment: @user536393 Oh. I wouldn't try messing with that. Ages ago I asked a question about the same thing and in the end it never got answered. I ended up wasting a bunch of time messing with it and never got it to work before I ended up just deleting Windows 10 because I never used it. Also, remember to click the check mark to accept an answer if it worked for you.